# Number of permutation with condition

Tags: combinatorics

Assume we have a group consisting of both women and men. (In my example it is 67 women and 43 men but that is not important.) The women are indistinguishable and the men are also indistinguishable.

In how many ways can we pick a subgroup consisting of $n$ women and $n$ men, i.e., the same number of women and men?

- For $n = 1$ I found the answer to be $2 = 2 \cdot 1$. ($\{(m,w), (w,m)\}$)
- For $n = 2$ I found the answer to be $6 = 3 \cdot 2$. ($\{(m,m,w,w), (w,w,m,m), (m,w,w,m), (w,m,m,w), (m,w,m,w), (w,m,w,m)\}$.)

Therefore, I assume that for a random number $n$, the answer is $n \cdot (n - 1)$.

How do I prove this?

**Update**

My assumption is wrong.

Comment: Why is the $n=1$ case not $67\cdot43$? I do not quite follow what your intention would be ...

Comment: Sorry. I forgot something; I meant to say that the women are indistinguishable and the men are also indistinguishable. Therefore you can pick $(m,w)$ or $(w,m)$, making to $2$ possibilities. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: In that case the answer should be $\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$. That matches your first case, but not the rest ...

Comment: BTW: Your username intrigued me. Greetings from DK to DK :o)

Comment: @String Greeting to you too, from Aarhus. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $2n$ spots and exactly $n$ of them must be chosen (e.g. for men to take them).

This can be done on $$\binom{2n}n$$ distinct ways.

---

**Edit**:

Let's do it for $n=3$. Give the men the numbers $1,2,3$ and give the women the numbers $4,5,6$. Then there are $6!$ arrangements, but e.g. arrangement $135462$ gives the same result as $326541$ (that is $mmwwwm$). So this result $mmwwwm$ is counted more than once. How many times is it counted? We can arrange $123$ on $3!$ ways (the men) and we can arrange $456$ on $3!$ ways (the women). That gives $3!3!$ possibilities that end up in $mmwwwm$. This is the case for each of these combinations so we must divide $6!$ by $3!3!$ to come to the real number.

Comment: Nice explanation as to why you are correct.

Comment: I have added a (maybe redundant) explanation.

Answer (score 2):

you asking is how many vectors of order $2n$ are there when in any cordinat there is a man or a woman such that their number is equal. Your answer is $$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}.$$ Therefore, for $3$ you are wrong.

Comment: I advice you to put brackets around $2n$.

Comment: @drhab , thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Ofir Schnabel. Can you maybe give an argument / a proof?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg without restrictions you have $(2n)!$ possibilities to arrenge $2n$ pepole in a row. Since your man and woman are undistingushed the you have to devide by the number of ways to arrange them in a row, this will be $n!$ to both of them.